# How to display an ascii85 encoded picture

Tags: image, ascii85

I try to display an ascii85 encoded image, like:

```
<img src='data:image/jpg;base85,...'/>
```

or

```
<img src='data:image/jpg;ascii85,...' />
```

I found several examples on base64 files, but nothing about ascii85...

What do you think?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it because, as far as I know, only PostScript and PDF are able to handle ascii85 (base85). Browsers are only handling base64 for now.

If you already have data in this encoding you will need convert it to base64 before putting it into the browser.

Comment: Is there any controls like canvas maybe that can handle it?

Comment: @UnBoug As far as I know it is not possible directly. You have to convert it first.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with some javascript/typescript.

- Have the code crawl the DOM
- find `img/@src` attributes that is `base85` encoded
- write the code to decode base85 and re-encode it in base64
- update the IMG src attribute back